# Sibling Communication

Tags: vue.js, communication, siblings

I've created a simple calendar app using Bootstrap-Vue b-container, 5 b-rows and 7 b-cols. Each cell is a day. Within that cell is child component called Day. Each day has a Date component that shows that cell's date. Each day can have 0 or more Payment components. When a Payment component is clicked on, the number in that component is highlighted, as shown in the right cell, below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ekB4.png)

When a different cell is clicked, I need to remove the highlight from the original Payment and then highlight the newly clicked Payment. How can I determine which Payment component needs to have the highlight removed?

Comment: You need to pass event to the parent and parent passes props to children about they state

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a coding question, feels more like app design. But if I were you, I'd have a "selectedDay" property in the parent Vue element that would point to the highlighted cell. And then I'd raise a "clicked" or "selected" event in the child element. In the parent, you can hook a method up for to event raised by the child and act accordingly.